# Need help on determining the time complexity of a square grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, time-complexity

So I am currently learning time complexity on my Data Structures class and I kind of got lost while doing an exercise. In the exercise I have a grid of 16 vertices so I have that `T(n)=T(16)`, so I would have that the total of edges equals 24. For the exercise I had to do a general formula for `T(n)`. The formula I used was `T(n)=[sqrt(n)*(sqrt(n)-1)]*2 = 2(n - sqrt(n))`. Now the part I got stuck is that the exercise  also asks me to prove that T(n) ϵ θ(n) by determining C1,C2 and n0. For that part I have done the following: `c1n <= 2n - 2sqrt(n) <= c2n`
                *Dividing by n: *

```
c1 <= 2 - 2/[sqrt(n)] <= c2
```

However I do not know how to proceed from there or if this is even the correct aproach to answering that part of the exercise. Any help on how to proceed would be greatly apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`sqrt(n)*sqrt(n) - 1 == n - 1`

Thus distributing the 2 gives `T(n)=2*n - 2` not `2(n - sqrt(n))`. I believe you have an arithmetic error.